# appending object values in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center"> <h6><label class="col-form-label small newvalues deduction">'+$.each( deductionname, function( i, val ) {console.log(val);return val + "<br>"  })+'</label></h6></div>\n\
```

I have this dynamically added on my page using Jquery the value of deduction is like this

```
["SSS:1000", "GSIS:1000"]
```

I want to have the value on top of each other but right now it is not what is happening is i am getting like this

`SSS:1000,GSIS:1000`

I dont get it because I added `<br>` on the dynamically adding of the values

I want them to be

```
SSS:1000,
GSIS:1000
```

Comment: So remove the `br`.

Comment: Please click the `<>` button and provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Mohammad i updated what i wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you're appending an `each()` call. The `return` value has no bearing on the string you're concatenating. Instead the array itself is coerced to a string, hence you see the plain `SSS:1000,GSIS:1000` output.

To fix this you can use `join()` to combine the values of the string before you concatenate them. Try this:

```js
var deductionname = ["SSS:1000", "GSIS:1000"];
var str = '<div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center"> <h6><label class="col-form-label small newvalues deduction">' + deductionname.join(',<br />') + '</label></h6></div>';

$('div').html(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is what i am looking for i just dont know how to search combining them with out loop. will need 9 mins to tick thank you